# Issues loading java class into gem in JRuby

Tags: ruby, jvm, rubygems, jruby

I am trying to add JRuby support to my C-extension gem, by writing a Java class and executing it when the gem is installed on JRuby.  The code in question lives on [this branch](https://github.com/dockyard/pg_array_parser/tree/jruby-compatibility), with the important files being the [java class](https://github.com/dockyard/pg_array_parser/blob/jruby-compatibility/ext/pg_array_parser/PgArrayParserService.java) and the code to [load it when used in JRuby](https://github.com/dockyard/pg_array_parser/blob/jruby-compatibility/lib/pg_array_parser.rb)

At this point, I am just trying to ensure I have my gem configured correctly, and fully expect it to fail the specs.

When I try to run rspec (or the gem in IRB for that matter) I get the following backtrace

```
NameError: cannot load Java class com.dockyard.PgArrayParser
  get_proxy_or_package_under_package at org/jruby/javasupport/JavaUtilities.java:54
                      method_missing at /Users/dan/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.6.7.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/shared/builtin/javasupport/java.rb:51
                       PgArrayParser at /Users/dan/Projects/dockyard/pg_array_parser/lib/pg_array_parser.rb:6
                              (root) at /Users/dan/Projects/dockyard/pg_array_parser/lib/pg_array_parser.rb:3
                             require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1033
                             require at /Users/dan/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.6.7.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36
                              (root) at /Users/dan/Projects/dockyard/pg_array_parser/lib/pg_array_parser.rb:2
                             require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1033
                             require at /Users/dan/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.6.7.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36
                              (root) at /Users/dan/Projects/dockyard/pg_array_parser/lib/pg_array_parser.rb:1
                             require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1033
                             require at /Users/dan/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.6.7.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36
                              (root) at /Users/dan/Projects/dockyard/pg_array_parser/spec/spec_helper.rb:1
                                load at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1058
                     load_spec_files at /Users/dan/Projects/dockyard/pg_array_parser/spec/parser_spec.rb:746
                             collect at org/jruby/RubyArray.java:2331
                     load_spec_files at /Users/dan/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.6.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.10.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:746
                                 run at /Users/dan/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.6.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.10.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:22
                                 run at /Users/dan/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.6.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.10.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:69
                             autorun at /Users/dan/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.6.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.10.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:10
                                call at org/jruby/RubyProc.java:270
                                call at org/jruby/RubyProc.java:224
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having recently worked on a [JRuby extension](https://github.com/tychobrailleur/fibonacci-jrubyext) myself, here are some of the gotchas which I have found through experiment -- and which seem to cause you problems too:

- The java package must match the Ruby module in which your class sits.  If your class is in the `PgArrayParser` module, your class must be in the `pgarrayparser` (all lowercase).
- If you want to instantiate a `PgArrayParserEngine` class, then you `BasicLibraryService` must be called `PgArrayParserEngineService`.
- When using `@JRubyMethod`, specify the name of the method.

I have found [Yoko's article](http://yokolet.blogspot.ie/2011/05/extending-jruby.html) on the subject most useful, along with this [recent post](http://huangzhimin.com/2012/08/23/how-to-write-a-jruby-gem-part-2/).

I have applied these different elements to your project [here](https://github.com/tychobrailleur/pg_array_parser/tree/jruby-compat), and I can call the method from IRB -- and the first spec passes!

Comment: If you want to submit this as a pull request, I would love to give you full credit for the help!